# Invalid expression term "else" | ; expected (C#)

Tags: c#

This is probably one of the weirdest errors I've come across so far.

```
private void BUEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                input2 = float.Parse(TBAnswer.Text);

                if (choice == 0)
                    TBAnswer.Text = (input1 + input2).ToString();
                else if (choice == 1)
                    TBAnswer.Text = (input1 - input2).ToString();
                    TBStored.Text = TBStored.Text + '-' + (input2).ToString();
                else if (choice == 2)
                    TBAnswer.Text = (input1 * input2).ToString();
                else
                    TBAnswer.Text = (input1 / input2).ToString();
                input1 = 0;
            }
```

Ever since I added line 9, line 10 has been shoving errors that I can't make any sense of. 
The "else" gets a red underline, saying that it's an invalid expression term, and "if" gets a red underline saying that a semi-colon is expected.

Any ideas? I've honestly got nothing here. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: OK, turns out this is the most rookie-ish error I've ever made. Thanks for the help! Wonder how long it would have taken me to see that by myself...

Comment: Just paste the code here instead of linking. There is a button in the editor that will format it nicely.

Comment: Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx

Comment: Others have already given the answer, but it's worth getting into the habit of frequently using the Format Document comment (Ctrl K, Ctrl D) which will indent your code correctly.  In this case you'd have seen it unindent the second line in your `choice==1` block, showing that it wasn't in the block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing { } around the second case statement.

```
  if (choice == 0)
       TBAnswer.Text = (input1 + input2).ToString();
   else if (choice == 1)
   {   // Added
       TBAnswer.Text = (input1 - input2).ToString();
       TBStored.Text = TBStored.Text + '-' + (input2).ToString();
   }   // Added
   else ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to enclose two lines in your code with brackets.

```
else if (choice == 1)
   TBAnswer.Text = (input1 - input2).ToString();
   TBStored.Text = TBStored.Text + '-' + (input2).ToString();
else if (choice == 2)
```

should be:

```
else if (choice == 1) {
   TBAnswer.Text = (input1 - input2).ToString();
   TBStored.Text = TBStored.Text + '-' + (input2).ToString();
} else if (choice == 2)
```

Comment: And this is why many coding guidelines suggest putting braces around every block in an if/else construction, even if they (currently) only consist of a single statement...

Comment: Personally, I don't use braces if I don't have to. I try to minimize number of characters in my code - mind you, I do use meaningful identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The second `else if` is two lines, and should therefore be in a block.

Since you don't use a block, the compiler sees the `if`statement is complete because it was not immediately followed by else or else if.

To fix this, simply make the second else a block:

```
            if (choice == 0)
                TBAnswer.Text = (input1 + input2).ToString();
            else if (choice == 1)
            {
                TBAnswer.Text = (input1 - input2).ToString();
                TBStored.Text = TBStored.Text + '-' + (input2).ToString();
            }
            else if (choice == 2)
                TBAnswer.Text = (input1 * input2).ToString();
            else
                TBAnswer.Text = (input1 / input2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Line by line explanation here, leaving the lines that are okay

```
private void BUEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          1:  input2 = float.Parse(TBAnswer.Text);

          2:  if (choice == 0)
          3:      TBAnswer.Text = (input1 + input2).ToString();
          4:  else if (choice == 1)
          5:      TBAnswer.Text = (input1 - input2).ToString();
          6:      TBStored.Text = TBStored.Text + '-' + (input2).ToString();
```

There MAY be a problem in line 6 that the "if" conditional if it needs to execute more than 1 statement will have to be enclosed in a block using flower brackets"{ }".

```
          7:  **else** if (choice == 2)
```

There is a problem in line 7 because the else should always be used in conjuction with IF. Since you did not use a bracket for the statements executed with the condition, the compiler saw a problem with the else statement-

```
          8:      TBAnswer.Text = (input1 * input2).ToString();
            else
                TBAnswer.Text = (input1 / input2).ToString();
            input1 = 0;
        }
```